# A function defined by $L^p$ integral is continuous on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Suppose $f$ is a measurable function on $X$, $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$, and
$$g(p)=\int_X|f|^p d\mu=||f||_p^p, (0<p<\infty)$$
Let $E=\{p|g(p)<\infty\}$. Assume $||f||_\infty >0$.

Prove $g$ is continuous on $E$.

I have proved $g$ is continuous on the interior of $E$. A hint is given that continuity of $g$ on $\partial E$ follows from monotonicity applying to $\chi_{|f|>1}f$ and $\chi_{|f|\le 1}f$.

Could you explain what does it mean and how to use it? I am a little confused about what my target is. I think I need to show if $r\in E$, but $\forall \epsilon>0, r-\epsilon \not\in E$, then $\lim_{p\to r^+}g(p)=g(r)$.

---

For a proof that $g$ is continuous on the interior of $E$, suppose $r<p<s,r,s\in E$, then $p=tr+(1-t)s$. By Holder's inequality, we know $p\in E$. Rewrite the relation, we have
$$g( tr+(1-t)s)\le g(r)^tg(s)^{(1-t)}$$
Since $x\to \log x$ is increasing, we have $$\log g( tr+(1-t)s)\le t \log(r) +(1-t)\log g(s),\forall t\in(0,1)$$ So $\log g$ is convex in $E^\circ$, so $\log g$ is continuous, hence $g$ is continuous  in $E^\circ$.

Comment: Divide the integral in two integrals. Study each integral.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Let me try. May you please elaborate it as an answer?

Comment: I will try tomorrow if there isn't answer.

Comment: Silly question: what is the border of $E$?.  $g$ continuous $\implies$ $E$ open $\implies$ $E\cap\partial E=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I am also a little confused about what the continuity means. But I think I need to show if $r\in E$, but $r-\epsilon \not\in E$, then $\lim_{p\to r^+}g(p)=g(r)$.

Comment: Continuity requires function defined in a neighborhood on the point: $(p_0-\epsilon,p_0+\epsilon)\subset E$ and $\lim_{p\to p_0}g(p)=g(p_0)$.

Comment: Add your proof to the post.

Comment: By the way, $||f||_\infty>0$ is necessary to take the composition $ \log\circ g$.

Comment: And for future reference, this is part (b) of Exercise 3.4 of Rudin's *Real And Complex Analysis* on p. 71.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r\in E$, but $r+\epsilon \not\in E$

Let $p_n \rightarrow r$ with each $p_n \leq r$ and $p_n\in E$.

Then we see that 
$|f|^{p_n} $ goes $|f|^{r}$ pointwise a.e.

Using the hint 
$$\lim_n \int |f|^{p_n} = \lim_n \int_{\{|f|<1\}} |f|^{p_n} + \lim_n \int_{\{|f|\geq 1\}} |f|^{p_n} $$

Try dominated convergence theorem on $\{|f|<1\}$, and try monotone convergence theorem on $\{|f|\geq 1\}$.

Comment: I think $|f|^{p_n}\to |f|^r$ if $|f|(x)\neq 0$. So why it's a.e converges? And what's the dominator of $|f|^{p_n}$ for $|f|<1$? Is $|f|^{p_1}$ OK?

Comment: What happens at $|f|(x) = 0$ when $p_n, r >0$? Could you give me a counter example? And for dominating function, $|f|^{p_1}$ will work, because $|f|^p$ is monotone decreasing  in $p$ when $|f|\in (0,1)$, and by assumption, $p_1 > r$

Comment: yeah, you are right.

Comment: I think your method works for any point in $E$, not necessary the boundary point. So actually I don't need to follow the special method to prove the continuity of interior point. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: when $p_n \rightarrow r$ is not one sided, you will lose the monotonicity in the 2nd integral, but dominated convergence theorem will work I think.

Comment: And just one more remark, the function $g$ does not have to be continuous on the boundary of $E$, it is only continuous on $E\cap \partial E$. If you look above, the 2nd part of the integral is allowed to be $+\infty$ using M.C.Thm unless we assume that $r\in E$. I think you knew this but you used $\partial E$ instead of $E\cap \partial E$ in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding.